# Find the maximum value of the function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, real-numbers

So I was just messing around with finding the maximum and minimum values of functions, and I came across this:

> $$ \text{Find the maximum value of}   \,\, f(x)=\frac1{x^{2x^2}}.$$

Any ideas?

Comment: what domain? there are several ways how one could approach this problem, one is certainly to study the derivative - you could also start by plotting the function and get some intuition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $x>0$. Then you get
$$
f'(x)=\frac{-2x\times (1+2 \ln x)}{x^{2 x^2}} .
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oops, looks like I made a blunder in differenciating the function. Stupid. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome.